# React Apollo and Redux: Combine custom reducers with Apollo state

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, graphql, react-apollo

When using `react-apollo` with redux, data from the server is cached in the redux store under an `apollo` key:

```
{
    apollo: // results from Apollo queries
}
```

After creating your own reducers and corresponding state tree, your store might look like this:

```
{
    apollo: { ... },
    ui: {
        selectedItem: 2;
        showItems: 6
    }
}
```

Imagine that there is an action which changes the value of `ui.selectedItem`, and that this value is the index of an item buried somewhere in the `apollo` object.

With [reducer composition](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/RefactoringReducersExample.html), reducers for our `ui` state will rightly have no access to anything under the Apollo state.

In our component we can subscribe to changes on our `ui` state via `mapStateToProps`, and we can map Apollo results to props using the `react-apollo` GraphQL container (or `@graphql` decorator).

But how can we update our store with values that are computed from Apollo results and other state in our application?

For example, if `apollo.item.list` is an array of items, and `ui.selectedItem` is the index you want to target in that list - how could the store contain a value for:

```
apollo.item.list[ui.selectedItem]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution was to use [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) to `compose` the store and Apollo states together via `mapProps`:

```
import { mapProps, compose } from ‘recompose’;

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  selectedItem: state.ui.selectedItem
})

const mapDataToProps = {
  props: ({ data }) => ({ list: data.item.list })
}

const selectProps = mapProps(({ selectedItem, list}) => ({
  item: list[selectedItem] 
}))

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, {}),
  graphql(MY_QUERY, mapDataToProps),
  selectProps
)(MyComponent);
```

This also allows us to check the `graphql` loading state using [branch](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#branch), so we don't run `selectProps` until the data is available.

Thanks to [Daniel Rearden's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44981204/3252835) for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

You're right -- with reducer composition, each reducer should not have access to the rest of the state. The question is why would you even need your **store** to contain a separate value for `apollo.item.list[ui.selectedItem]`.

Presumably you need this value to render the correct item inside your container. To calculate it, you just need an appropriate selector to call within mapStateToProps. Pass in the whole state, get the value you need. A simplified example:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  itemToShow: itemSelector(state)
})

const itemSelector = ({ apollo, ui }) => apollo.item.list[ui.selectedItem]
```

You'll need to wrap your container in both the `connect` and `graphql` HOCs to make that work, although as far as I can tell, whether you wrap it in one or the other first doesn't seem to matter. You can also look into using [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) which is ideal for derived data like this.

**Edit:** Since Apollo's chunk of the store wasn't really designed to be used as described above, you may find it easier to break this up into two steps instead: First, assign ui.selectedItem to a prop in mapStateToProps. Then, if you wrap your container with the graphql HOC, you can reference that prop like so:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ selectedItem });
const mapDataToProps = ({ ownProps: { selectedItem }, data }) => ({
  itemToShow: data.item.list[selectedItem]
});
const ContainerWithData = graphql(myQuery, { props: mapDataToProps })(MyContainer);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ContainerWithData);
```

Or you could use apollo-react's `compose` for a cleaner approach.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful input. I like the first solution because of the memoization option and reusable selectors (I might need this in more than one container - hence wanting to store it in the first place). But as you say, it's not really a reliable way of using Apollo. The second option seems to put a lot of work into the `graphql` conrtainer and doesn't seem to be reusable across containers?

Comment: Also, the second option would only seem to work when the data changes. If the selectedItem state changed after that, the `itemToShow` value wouldn't get updated?

Comment: Hi Daniel, can we access `apollo.item.list` directly inside reselect selectors. Would the selector re run if `apollo.item` is updated?

Comment: @Anirudha this question is dated. Apollo no longer uses a redux store under the hood. The use case described in the original question would be better solved by utilizing Apollo [local state](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state/).

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer to your question, but I found that [ReactQL](https://reactql.org/) is a great starter kit that takes care of all those things for you. It has all the boilerplate for Apollo+React+Redux including custom Redux reducers. See how they did it.