# Map query to props with Apollo.js in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, graphql, apollo

I have just set up graphql on my server and wanting to connect Apollo to my frontend.

I was able to integrate Apollo with Redux ([How to pass initial state to reducer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45134512/how-to-pass-initial-state-to-reducer/45134730#45134730)) but now want to map state to props via redux connect.

My current Home component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

import './Home.css'

class Home extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <section className='home-container'>
        <h1>Site Name</h1>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    curPage: state.curPage
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
)(Home)
```

I essentially want to replace `mapStateToProps` with `mapQueryToProps` however I am unsure how this works.

Does this make a request to my `/graphql` endpoint and map the response to `curPage`?

Will this happen before the first render? As in will `this.props.curPage` be available within `componentWillMount()`? (I need this for seo purposes to make sure all the content is rendered server side).

Where do I configure my graphql endpoint? I see some examples configuring it within their store. My store is split into store.js and index.js slightly but is as follows:

// index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './containers/App/App';

import initialState from './initialState';
import configureStore from './store';

import { ApolloClient, ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';

const client = new ApolloClient();

// Let the reducers handle initial state

initState() // eslint-disable-line

// if we are in production mode, we get the initial state from the window object, otherwise, when we are in dev env we get it from a static file
const preloadedState = window.__INITIAL_STATE__ === '{{__PRELOADEDSTATE__}}' ? initialState : window.__INITIAL_STATE__

const store = configureStore(preloadedState)

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider store={store} client={client}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

// store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import reducers from './reducers'
import { ApolloClient } from 'react-apollo';

const logger = createLogger()
const client = new ApolloClient();

export default function configureStore(initialState = {}) {

  // Create the store with two middlewares
  const middlewares = [
  //  sagaMiddleware
    logger,
    client.middleware()
  ]

  const enhancers = [
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
  ]

  const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    initialState,
    compose(...enhancers)
  )

  // Extensions
  store.asyncReducers = {} // Async reducer registry

  return store
}
```

**Update**

I am now importing my client from my store so that I only have one instance of my client. I am also using `/graphql` as my endpoint so I shouldn't need to configure the endpoint.

// index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './containers/App/App';

import initialState from './initialState';
import {configureStore, client} from './store';

import { ApolloClient, ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';

initState() // eslint-disable-line

// if we are in production mode, we get the initial state from the window object, otherwise, when we are in dev env we get it from a static file
const preloadedState = window.__INITIAL_STATE__ === '{{__PRELOADEDSTATE__}}' ? initialState : window.__INITIAL_STATE__

const store = configureStore(preloadedState)

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider store={store} client={client}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Still a bit confused about `graphql(MY_QUERY, { props: mapQueryToProps })(Home)`

I have a query to get curPage which works in graphiql: (I'm guessing `MY_QUERY` should be equal to this?)

```
query {
  findResource(filter: {resource: "pages", slug: "about"}) {
    id
    title
    slug
    path
    sections
  }
}
```

and returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "findResource": [
      {
        "id": "5",
        "title": "About",
        "slug": "about",
        "path": "/about",
        "sections": [
          {
            "type": "masthead",
            "mh_title": "",
            "video": false,
            "image": [],
            "showCta": false,
            "cta": []
          },
          {
            "type": "text_image",
            "alignment": "left",
            "text_image": [
              {
                "type": "text",
                "title": "",
                "content": "",
                "call_to_action": false,
                "cta": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Would that mean my

```
const mapQueryToProps = ({data: { getPage: { page } }, ownProps}) => ({ curPage: page })
```

should look like:

```
const mapQueryToProps = ({data: { findResource: { page } }, ownProps}) => ({ curPage: page })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of points:

You're creating two instances of ApolloClient -- one in `index.js` and one in `store.js` -- you could pass the client to configureStore and that way you're utilizing the same instance.

If your graphQL endpoint is anywhere other than `/graphql`, you'll have to utilize a custom network interface. [Example from the docs](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/initialization.html):

```
import { ApolloClient, createNetworkInterface } from 'react-apollo';
const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
  uri: 'http://api.example.com/graphql'
});
const client = new ApolloClient({ networkInterface });
```

With just the minimal setup, the data from your query will not be available immediately -- the component will mount and rerender once the data is available. However, [the documentation provides a couple of ways to get around that](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/server-side-rendering.html).

As far as how the query data gets mapped to props, it's important to note that Apollo does not utilize `connect`, but rather has its own HOC. You'll use it in a similar manner:

```
graphql(MY_QUERY, { props: mapQueryToProps })(Home)
```

The function you assign to props will be passed a single object that has two properties, `data` and `ownProps`. Data includes the result of your query and ownProps refers to any existing props on the component. So your mapQueryToProps might look something like:

```
const mapQueryToProps = ({data: { getPage: { page } }, ownProps}) =>
  ({ curPage: page })
```

You can also omit specifying `props` altogether, and you'll just get the whole `data` object as a prop. The above is just a way of fine-tuning what actually gets assigned as props to your component.

If there are still parts of your state you want to keep using redux for, there's a section in the docs for integrating redux and Apollo. It's pretty clean if you use compose or [recompose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975471/react-apollo-and-redux-combine-custom-reducers-with-apollo-state/45010381#45010381).

Apollo's documentation for react is pretty clear and to-the-point. If you haven't already, you may want to just go through the `Setup and options` and `Usage` sections, and maybe even through any applicable `Recipes` before proceeding any further.

**EDIT:** The query you pass in to the HOC will need to be a string. The easiest thing to do is to import and use the `gql` tag. Based on the query you provided, it would look like this:

```
const MY_QUERY = gql`
  query {
    findResource(filter: {resource: "pages", slug: "about"}) {
      id
      title
      slug
      path
      sections
    }
  }`
```

Comment: Ok so I have made the changes to the client as per your recommendation. I have updated my original post with the way I have done this. Secondly I am still a little unsure about how to mapQueryToProps. I have updated my original post with another example. Am I on the right track? I have read the documentation you suggested as well.

Comment: See my edit for how to pass in the query. You can read more [here](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/queries.html#basics). As far as the mapQueryToProps... In my exampe, I was just guessing at what your data structure would be; look at what the query's returning -- that's the data object you're working with in mapQueryToProps. I'm guessing you need the first object inside the array that's returned so you could just do something like: ({data}) => ({curPage: data.findResource[0]}).

Comment: Or don't worry about setting the props for a simple case like this. Just do `graphql(MY_QUERY)(Home)` and then you can access the data inside your component with `props.data`. Might be less of a headache.

Comment: any idea why I would be getting `Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context of "Apollo(Home)". Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>`? As you can see in my index.js I am wrapping my `App` in `<ApolloProvider>`